# Swagger 2.0 Anyof

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

What is the equivalent of anyof in Swagger version 2.0, Please tell me how to update my json file because I want to upgrade my documentation from swagger 1.0 to 2.0.

Thank You for your Help.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think there is one and it feels like a big shortcoming. It's definitely not mentioned in [the Schema Object portion of the specification](https://swagger.io/specification/v2/#schemaObject). They call out the elements there that have been adopted from the JSON Schema and `anyOf` isn't among them:

> The following properties are taken directly from the JSON Schema definition and follow the same specifications:
>
> - $ref - As a JSON Reference
> - format (See Data Type Formats for further details)
> - title
> - description (GFM syntax can be used for rich text representation)
> - default (Unlike JSON Schema, the value MUST conform to the defined type for the Schema Object)
> - multipleOf
> - maximum
> - exclusiveMaximum
> - minimum
> - exclusiveMinimum
> - maxLength
> - minLength
> - pattern
> - maxItems
> - minItems
> - uniqueItems
> - maxProperties
> - minProperties
> - required
> - enum
> - type
>
> The following properties are taken from the JSON Schema definition but their definitions were adjusted to the Swagger Specification. Their definition is the same as the one from JSON Schema, only where the original definition references the JSON Schema definition, the Schema Object definition is used instead.
>
> - items
> - allOf
> - properties
> - additionalProperties

I think the closest thing is the `discriminator` field, but that means you've got to structure your output to accommodate Swagger.

Answer (score 7):

`anyOf` and `oneOf` are now supported in [OpenAPI Specification 3.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md) (released on July 26, 2017).

Comment: openapi 3.0 is not a proper superset of swagger 2.0. Switching will likely result in invalidating other parts of the document. May still be worth it, but it's not painless.

Comment: @Tom there are [OpenAPI 2.0-to-3.0 converters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59749513/113116) to assist with migration.