# Swagger Annotations usage for anyof

Tags: swagger

I have a group of objects of a particular type.  I'm trying (through annotations) to specify an anyof relationship to classes that are annotated as @ApiModel with a parent specified.

It looks to me as though the functionality to specify anyof does not exist.  Does anyone have any information regarding how to accomplish anyof utilizing the swagger annotations??

Thanks!!

Comment: `anyOf` or `allOf`? `anyOf` is not supported in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, it [will be supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34863160/113116) in the upcoming OpenAPI Specification 3.0.