# How to convert OpenAPI 2.0 to OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Are there any tools/libraries to convert OpenAPI 2.0 definitions to OpenAPI 3.0, without doing it one per row?

Comment: Related: [Convert OpenAPI 3.0 to Swagger 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56637299/113116)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

### Swagger Editor

Paste your OpenAPI 2.0 definition into https://editor.swagger.io and select **Edit > Convert to OpenAPI 3** from the menu.

[image: Swagger Editor conversion from OpenAPI 2.0 to OpenAPI 3.0]

### Swagger Converter

Converts OpenAPI 2.0 and Swagger 1.x definitions to OpenAPI 3.0.

```
https://converter.swagger.io/api/convert?url=OAS2_YAML_OR_JSON_URL
```

This gives you JSON. If you want YAML, send the request with the `Accept: application/yaml` header:

```
curl "https://converter.swagger.io/api/convert?url=OAS2_YAML_OR_JSON_URL" -H "Accept: application/yaml" -o ./openapi.yaml
```

API docs: https://converter.swagger.io

GitHub repo: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-converter

### Swagger Codegen version 3.x

Can also convert OpenAPI 2.0 and Swagger 1.x definitions to OpenAPI 3.0. Swagger Codegen has a CLI version, [Maven plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/3.0.0/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin), [Docker images](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/3.0.0#public-pre-built-docker-images).

Here's an example using the command-line version (you can download the latest JAR from [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.codegen.v3/swagger-codegen-cli)). Write the entire command *on one line*. Use `openapi-yaml` to get YAML or `openapi` to get JSON.

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.19.jar generate
     -l openapi-yaml
     -i https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.yaml
     -o OUT_DIR
```

GitHub repo: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen

Comment: BTW: It can also be achieved with `openapi-generator-cli`: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator .

Comment: @MichalFoksa Feel free to post an answer with openapi-generator usage example. There are a few other converters (Mermade, API Transformer, ...), I just listed those that I've personally used.

Comment: Note that Swagger Editor also uses the online converter. It shows a message before doing so: "Swagger Editor's contents will be sent to https://converter.swagger.io/api/convert".

Comment: `openapi-generator-cli` uses `-g` instead of `-l` shown here. Otherwise, seems to work similarly.

Comment: [swagger2openapi](https://github.com/Mermade/oas-kit/blob/main/packages/swagger2openapi/README.md) can also convert OpenAPI 2.0 to OpenAPI 3.0

Comment: This no longer appears to be an option in that menu...

Comment: @meawoppl [it's a bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/3055)

Comment: @meawoppl the issue with the missing "Convert to OpenAPI 3" command was [fixed](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/pull/3083) in Swagger Editor v. 4.2.9. The command is now visible again on https://editor.swagger.io.

Comment: If you wanna run with swagger2openapi you wan use this command:         swagger2openapi --yaml --outfile "$path/${service}.yaml" "$path/${service}.json"