# Maven plugin for converting OpenApi 2.0 to OpenApi 3.0

Tags: swagger, generator, specifications, openapi, converters

Related to [How to convert OpenAPI 2.0 to OpenAPI 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749513/how-to-convert-openapi-2-0-to-openapi-3-0) i know that there are some external tools to convert OpenApi 2.0 to 3.0, but I need to convert and generate it while building maven project. 
Are there any maven plugins to convert existing OpenApi2.0.yaml specification file into OpenApi3.0.yaml specification file during building process?

Comment: I've found that openapi-generator-maven-plugin can do that with openapi as generatorName

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749513/how-to-convert-openapi-2-0-to-openapi-3-0