# Swagger Documentation error `Should be object`

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm manually writing swagger documentation. But I'm getting some error `Should be object`

I don't know why I'm getting error in below code.

```
events:
        $ref: "#/def/Events"

Events:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/def/ClassRef'
        - $ref: '#/def/TypeRef'
        - $ref: '#/def/EventRef'
        - $ref: '#/def/MarketRef'
        - $ref: '#/def/OutcomeRef'

  ClassRef:  # <--- I get the "should be object" error here
    type: "object"
    properties:
      classRef:
        type: "string"
        
  TypeRef:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      typeRef:
        type: "string"
        
  EventRef:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      eventRef:
        type: "string"
        
  MarketRef:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      marketRef:
        type: "string"
  
  OutcomeRef:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      outcomeRef:
        type: "string"
```

I'm getting this error in ClassRef line. Can some one help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`) does not support `oneOf`, you need OpenAPI 3.0 (`openapi: 3.0.0`) to use `oneOf`.

Assuming you use OpenAPI 3.0, and all schemas live in the `components/schemas` section, change the `Events` schema as follows:

```yaml
Events:
  oneOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ClassRef'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/TypeRef'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/EventRef'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/MarketRef'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OutcomeRef'
```

Comment: But if we use 2.0, how to resolve this? We are still using Swagger 2.0

Comment: In 2.0 the most you can do is define `Events` as just `type: object`, that is, a free-form object with arbitrary properties. But if you need `oneOf` you need to migrate to OpenAPI 3.0. There are tools to [convert OpenAPI 2.0 to OpenAPI 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59749513/113116).

Comment: Thank you. You have saved my day