# Generate Swagger OpenApi Spec 3.0 using Swashbuckle in Asp.Net Framework WebApi

Tags: swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

Swashbuckle version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net451" generates **"swagger": "2.0"** spec.Is there any way to generate 3.0 spec?

In Asp.Net Core we can generate 3.0, what about in Asp.Net Framework WebApi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike Swashbukle.AspNetCore, Swashbuckle for WebAPI [does not support OpenAPI 3.0](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/1092).

As a workaround, you can use Swashbuckle to generate a `swagger: '2.0'` definition and [convert the generated file to OpenAPI 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59749691/113116) separately.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to use OpenAPI 3.0 on .NET Framework projects?

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: @jet_choong did you find anything?

Comment: this is not helping us; cause the 2.0 is not generating nullable types correctly, e.g. double? is generated as double; and even if we translate it to 3.0 it still is reflected as doublle type cause it doesn't know it is actually a double?, nullable type.
any suggestion on how to fix this case? thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Recommend the Nswag.

Key settings.

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.