# How to convert swagger.json to openapi3 spec

Tags: swagger

I'm looking for a solution of converting swagger.json (generated by swagger2) to openapi3 json file in my CI/CD process (Git Actions).

I'm doing my job with Java, and I found some ways like:

1. Swagger inspector -> I guess it works in web env only.
2. SwaggerHub gradle plugin
3. Swagger codegen

but I have no experience of my task. which one is proper way to solve my problem? or is there any other way?

grateful for reading my question :)

Comment: Related: [How to convert OpenAPI 2.0 to OpenAPI 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59749513/113116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renew) I solved it completely, with using Swagger-parser

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser

example code is here:

```
@Test
public void parsingTest() throws Exception {
    String outputDir = System.getProperty(YOUR_PATH_HERE);
    SwaggerParseResult result = new OpenAPIParser().readLocation(YOUR_PATH_HERE, null, null);
    OpenAPI api = result.getOpenAPI();

    // POJO -> JSON
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.writeValue(new File(YOUR_PATH_HERE), api);
}
```

hope it makes helpful someone!

Comment: What about adding a link to `Swagger2markup` and some example code. This way others can benefit from you answer.

Comment: Hi. I read your advice and I'll update my answer. Thank you for your advice :)